# Choosing TeX distribution in AUCTeX

Tags: emacs, auctex

I'm using AUCTeX version 11.86 in GNU Emacs 23.2.1 in Windows 7, and I've just updated MiKTeX from version 2.8 to 2.9. How do I tell AUCTeX to use version 2.9 rather than 2.8?

A similar hypothetical question would be: if I had both MiKTeX and TeX Live, how would I tell AUCTeX which one to use?

The AUCTeX manual says

> Should you need to change the executable names related to the
>   different engine settings, there are some variables you can tweak.
>   Those are TeX-command, LaTeX-command, TeX- Omega-command,
>   LaTeX-Omega-command, ConTeXt-engine and ConTeXt-Omega-engine.

but I don't know how to do that (I'm not even sure it's the right thing to do) because my knowledge of Emacs is very superficial.

Answer (score 1):

To set a variable in [Elisp](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/) you use the `setq` function like this:

> (setq TeX-command "/usr/local/share/special/bin/tex")

(The AUCTeX manual should give you information about what each variable should be set to.)

If you put the `setq` commands (one for each variable you want to set) into your emacs init file (`~/.emacs` for a Unix like OS) then those settings will be used every time you launch emacs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem was that I didn't know which variable(s) to set. I got it working by editing the path in Windows.